# map key in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

It is possible change form key in JSON from key in double quotes to key without quotes?

from

```
let a = {
   "key1": "value1",
   "key2": "value2",
   "key3": "value3"
}
```

to

```
let b = {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2",
    key3: "value3"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a valid JavaScript Object, but it is not valid JSON:

```
let b = {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2",
    key3: "value3"
}
```

If you are writing JavaScript, you can do it like that without issues.

You can also use single quotes or grave accents. These are both valid:

```
let b = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2',
    key3: 'value3'
}
```

and

```
let b = {
    key1: `value1`,
    key2: `value2`,
    key3: `value3`
}
```

In some situations, you need to include the single, double, or grave accents. For example, when your **key starts with a number or has spaces in it**:

You would need them for this:

```
let obj = {
  '0key': 'value'
}
```

and this:

```
let obj = {
  'john smith': 'value'
}
```

Here is some supplementary reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics

Consider `dot notation` while you are asking if it is valid.

`b.key1` is valid dot notation, but `b.0` is not, and neither is `b.john smith`.

The other notation is `bracket notation` which allows you to refer to keys that do not work with dot notation.

`b['key1']` is valid bracket notation, and so is `b['0']` and `b['john smith']`.

Comment: "The only times" --- those are far from the exhaustive list of the cases when you need to enclose it in the quotes.

Comment: Yes I should be more clear. I will see if I can find a better list, perhaps from MDN.

Comment: The easiest would be: "If it's not a valid identifier - it should be put in quotes"